# Why isn't my Intel AX210 wireless card's bluetooth controller appearing on my Pop!_OS install?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, pop-os, intel

I bought an Intel AX210NGW wireless card. I am running Pop!_OS 22.04 on linux kernel 6.2.6. The WiFi works like a charm and at full speed, however I can't even get the bluetooth controller within the card to show up in `dmesg` or any device tree listings. Nothing appears on boot (cold from BIOS or warm), and I'm reasonably sure I have a legit card, not a knockoff or something. How can I get bluetooth working? I have tried almost every remedy I've seen, including pulling linux-firmware straight from git.kernel.org. I have not tried using a different kernel, but I would like to avoid that if possible. I'm not knowledgeable enough with the Linux kernel to file an issue if it is a kernel bug, or a regression from the first kernel properly supporting Intel AX210.

Below is some system information:

`sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[    9.723185] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.723246] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    9.723250] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.723259] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.723264] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.723275] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.990883] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    9.990895] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    9.990898] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    9.990947] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    9.990951] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    9.990983] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   10.009924] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   10.045913] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   10.045952] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   10.045956] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   10.045980] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   56.033198] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   56.033209] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   56.033219] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i hci0` yields no results.

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

here's my `uname -sr` kernel version:

```
Linux 6.2.6-76060206-generic
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800/CE2700 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b446 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`nmcli --get-values GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.TYPE device show`:

```
wlp2s0
wifi

virbr0
bridge

p2p-dev-wlp2s0
wifi-p2p

enp1s0
ethernet

lo
loopback
```